# Bootstrap - using two navbars

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap 3 and I am trying to use two navbars in the same page.

Here is a fiddle of my current implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/SSJVegito/30x80qq8/1/

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-position {
position: relative;}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-position" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Button</button>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
                <div class="navbar-text">Text</div>
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem I have is that I want to use a relative positioning as presented in the fiddle, but when I try this, it adds a spacing between the two navbars, which I don't want. I want them to be one after the other. I've searched quite a bit, but I couldn't find an answer. The closest thing I found was a solution with two navbars separated by a div.

Thanks!

Comment: .navbar {
    margin-bottom:0;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap navbars have a bottom margin by default so just add the following to your css to remove the space:

```
.navbar {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick indeed. Thanks, I will accept this answer as soon as stack overflow allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following to the CSS

```
.navbar{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/30x80qq8/5/)**